# What is .rank_ and .singular_ in linear regression?

Tags: python, machine-learning, math, scikit-learn

I am trying to understand linear regression in sklearn documentation and I stumbled upon the attributes section, and I don't know what the `.rank_` and `.singular_` represent. There is no comprehensive explanation in the documentation.

I have this as an example

```
>>> from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

>>> model.rank_ 
13

>>> model.singular_
array([3.54353952e+03, 1.57609582e+03, 5.69911549e+02, 3.26708222e+02,
       1.41541547e+02, 1.05019683e+02, 7.89006614e+01, 6.08655030e+01,
       3.64069654e+01, 2.13508221e+01, 1.03249311e+01, 4.64668118e+00,
       1.12979776e+00])
```

**How can I explain these values/attributes?**

You can also leave me link/s to the math concepts related to the`.ranks_` and `.singular_` for me to study.

Answer (score 1):

From [the source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/8881bbffb92d4f428aef12bd025815df9d4a9e5e/sklearn/linear_model/_base.py#L585-L589):

```
    rank_ : int
        Rank of matrix `X`. Only available when `X` is dense.
    singular_ : array of shape (min(X, y),)
        Singular values of `X`. Only available when `X` is dense.
```

Both are computed by [scipy.linalg.lstsq](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/34506555aa9d222e26db57964cd195650efcc9d7/scipy/linalg/_basic.py#L1066-L1070) which in turn calls [LAPACK:?gelsd](https://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d7/d3b/group__double_g_esolve_ga94bd4a63a6dacf523e25ff617719f752.html). The singular value decomposition (SVD) is introduced in [Lecture 4](https://books.google.ch/books?id=JaPtxOytY7kC&lpg=PR1&hl=de&pg=PA25) from Trefethen, Lloyd N., and David Bau III. Numerical linear algebra. Vol. 50. Siam, 1997.